# Wh-word as subject

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses

**1.**

> The thing which you need is a good sleep.

Which you need: relative clause
The thing: subject
A good sleep: complement

**2.**

> The boxes come from what I believe was a Javanese illuminated manuscript painted on wood I saw at the library.

> The boxes come from the thing which I believe was a Javanese illuminated manuscript...

If we drop **I believe**:

> The boxes come from the thing which was a Javanese illuminated manuscript...

**Which** here is working as the subject. But if we replace here **the thing which** with **what**:

> The boxes come from what was a Javanese illuminated manuscript painted on wood I saw at the library.

Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Yes: it's a 'fused' relative construction where "what" is interpreted as "the thing which"

Comment: In 1. the subject of the sentence is not just "the thing" but "the thing which you need". The subject of the relative clause is "which".

Comment: @BillJ thankyou. You have answered many of my questions in past. One thing I notice in all of them that the grammatical terms you use are very much based on Descriptive grammar and I only find them in a book written by Huddleston, Pulum and several others which is 'The Cambridge grammar of the English Language 2002'. So I m just curious and can't help but ask that you have read that book

Comment: My answers are based on my opinions about the grammar, which are based on generally accepted modern grammar. The only real differences here are that I prefer to use the term 'fused relative construction' in preference to 'nominal relative clause', and _what was a Javanese illuminated manuscript ..._ a noun phrase, not a clause. They did come from H&P.

Comment: Note my last comment on MarcInManhattan's thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your revision is fine.

> The boxes come from the thing which was a Javanese illuminated manuscript . . .

Here, the pronoun "which" introduces a relative clause. "The thing" functions as the object of the preposition "from" and is modified by the relative clause.

> The boxes come from what was a Javanese illuminated manuscript . . .

Here, the pronoun "what" introduces a nominal clause. The entire nominal clause functions as the object of the preposition "from".

Comment: @MarclnManhattan 'The boxes come from the thing which I believe was a Javanese illuminated manuscript...'  as u just said 'which' is introducing here the relative clause. 'Which' here works as The object of 'I believe'. Is it also working as the subject of 'was a javanese illuminated manuscript...'? Bcz 'the thing' can't connect itself with 'was a Javanese Manuscript'. Without using 'which' in between them.

Comment: @RADS No: In _The boxes come from the thing which I believe was a Javanese illuminated manuscript_, "which" is subject of the "was" clause.

Comment: Note, though, that _The boxes come from the thing [which I believe was a Javanese illuminated manuscript painted on wood] [which I saw at the library]_ is a special relative construction called 'stacking'. Here, the antecedent for the second relative clause is the NP _thing which I believe was a Javanese illuminated manuscript painted on wood_.